# Image onload seems to be called early when I pass in image data string (base 64)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onload

I am having a small bug which seems to indicate that the onload function is being called prior to the image being fully loaded, when you pass in image data as its source.

This is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='finalImage'></canvas>
</body>
</html>​
```

This is the javascript:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    // I've also put a console.log here at one point, and it does get called.
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QNMR..."; // cut for sanity.

var outputCanvas = $("#finalImage")[0];
var outputContext = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');

// If I uncomment this line, the image is drawn.
//context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// If I change canvas to image, its also drawn, which means it is being loaded.
// But it seems to indicate to me that onload gets called too early.
outputContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);​
```

[Here is the link to the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ruKht/12/).

Let me know if you find what is wrong with it, been messing with it for quite a bit now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);​` calls before `context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` to guarantee that `outputContext` is drawn to after `canvas` is to put it in the onload function

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
var outputCanvas = $("#finalImage")[0];
var outputContext = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');
image.onload = function() {
    // I've also put a console.log here at one point, and it does get called.
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    outputContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);​
};
image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QNMR..."; // cut for sanity.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ruKht/14/

Comment: Yup, that's right. Definitely missed that. Thanks for the help!